# How do I add a back wall to the front wall, so the object would be more than one layer of vertices?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges, 3d-printing, wireframe

So, I'm preparing a 3D model in blender for 3D printing and I split it into multiple parts, so I could print them out separately and fit electronics between the parts. However, now I'm at the problem where I have split an object into 2 and I have a front wall but separated back wall into another object (so it's one layer), and I need the object to have 2 layers (front wall and back wall) to be able to print out.
So here I am because I don't know how to formulate it to ask google and get a result which would help me.
I guess it has to be thicker than one layer of vortex walls?
Sorry for my terrible explaining, I'm not familiar with keywords for blender.
Any resources or a comment explaining how to do it would be a huge help, Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the blend file? Geometry is hard to see in wireframe+single image (what is depth what is hole). Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for that.

Comment: I added the file, you can check it out.